# Allow app to access private key in keychain

Tags: macos, desktop-application, keychain

I'm developing a macos app that has to access certificates in the keychain. I would like to automatically test the app, but macos always gives me the prompt for the password for access to the private key of the certificate. Is there a way to automatically allow my app access to the certificate and keychain. I tried to [import](https://ss64.com/osx/security-export.html) the certificate with the -T option with the security tool but that unfortunately didn't work.
[image]

Comment: Appears to be related or even a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088111/macos-wants-to-make-changes-enter-an-administrator-s-name-and-password-to-allow/65124174#65124174)

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you. Do you perhaps know if this can also be done from a script using a command similar to `security`.