# Asking for keychain access multiple times every time I make a testflight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keychain, testflight

I'm trying to make a testflight for an app but every time a try to build the app for production I get asked to give system access to the keychain.

[Keychain login picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saCb7.png)

The problem is that even if a login is asking me again to login over and over again. I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.4 .

Comment: Check the configuration of archive folder. Also check permissions with disk utility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [macOS wants to make changes.Enter an administrator’s name and password to allow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088111/macos-wants-to-make-changes-enter-an-administrator-s-name-and-password-to-allow)