# Always allow is gone, how to get it back?

Tags: operating-system, keychain, simulator

[Always allow is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1UmL.png)

When I try to build to a physical device, it suddenly asks for permissions, which is fine, but not that I should repeat myself 14 times, each time building for a device. Exhausting...

- I tried to reinstall VS for Mac 2022.
- Tried to update OS.
- I tried to run it in Xcode but had the same issue.

Comment: "Tried to run in xcode, same issue" surely suggests that this is not a visual studio problem, as you've tagged, and is likely due to an OS issue instead. Searching around, you're not the first to suffer from this problem if you search on "always allow" and *keychain*.

Comment: Thanks, updated tags! Yes, i have only found others with same problems, but no solutions yet...

Comment: Found the exact private key in keychain access, and allowed it always. Work around, but seems to be working.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088111/macos-wants-to-make-changes-enter-an-administrator-s-name-and-password-to-allow/65124174#65124174) post? That might just solve your issue